# Passing "this" as a parameter vuejs 2

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, this, warnings

Im trying to pass a vuejs object (Object A) as a parameter (into Object B) so that I can access all the methods and variables without passing them all separately as params.

So it looks like this:

```
<!-- In Object A -->
<ObjectB :pass_obj="this"/>
```

Definition of Object B:

```
<template>
...
</template>

<script>
...

props: {
    pass_obj: {
      type: Object,
      default () {
        return {
        }
      }
    }
  },
<script>
```

By doing so in Object B I can access methods of Object A.

```
<!-- in Object B -->
this.pass_obj.foo();
```

It helps me to strucutre the code more modularly and Object B can interact with the coresponding methods of each class it has been implemented into.

The issue is that I get the following warning in the browser console:

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "__v_isRef" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property. See: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Declaring-Reactive-Properties.

I undersand it's because "this" is not defined in the `data() { return {...} }` of the Object A. But even if I define it there like (which is propably a terrible practise):

```
data() { 
return {
this: this
...
} 
}
```

I still get the warning.

How do I avoid getting this warning. And maybe should I rethink this approach. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: In my opinion you should definitely rethink the approach.  Child components shouldn't directly access parent methods as it tightly couples them together.  If you want the child to signal to a parent to run a method, the child should emit an event. The parent then listens for events and reacts accordingly, and different parents can react differently. The child and parent are then completely independent, and that is true modular programming,

Comment: No need to define in the data just ```this.$emit("passOBJ, {object:data}")``` the value from **B** then receive the value from **A** by <ObjectB @passOBJ="passOBJ($event)"/>

Comment: Vue is one way binding. That means data flows in one direction, in order to update data of parent component we usually use ```this.$emit('event-name', {})``` or vuex.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I will look closer on these events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the parent component instance from a child component, you can use [`$parent`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-the-Parent-Component-Instance) property. This can be tempting to reach for as a lazy alternative to passing data with a prop.

As an example, If you want to access parent component `foo()` method from a child component, Use `this.$parent.foo()`.